# How to close connection objects created for Gcp-Storage and pub-sub using Google Cloud Platform's python libraries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

My application is creating pub-sub objects using:

```
google.cloud import pubsub_v1
publisher_client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient
```

and storage objects using:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
```

how  can I quickly and gracefully  close/release these connection objects  so that can be used at scale?

Comment: This client instances does not create a connection and keep it up, so even if you create many instances it will not flood your connections. They are just objects. You can delete both using `del publisher_client` and `del client`. For The Pubsub object, before `del` it, call the function `publisher_client.stop()` to publish all outstanding messages. And for the storage call `client.close()` before del. Documentation is not clear about it, but seams it closes files opened to be uploaded. Please inform if it works for you so I can post a final answer.

Comment: It works for pub-sub but I could't find any close() method for the storage client. There is on for a BigQuery connection object though. I am tempted to test the `del client` for storage as well.

Comment: About these are just objects:
When I run my app at scale, I get the following error message when creating these objects.
e.g. For storage: \"/opt/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py\", line 483, in default\n    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)\ngoogle.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application

Comment: This is has no relation with the objects creation / deletion. You have to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable with the credentials file to a service account with proper rights. Check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually) with the details.

Comment: I agree. But I see these errors only at scale. These are accompanied by the following : "Cannot invoke RPC on closed channel!"
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/channel.pyx.pxi", line 498, in grpc._cython.cygrpc.Channel.segregated_call
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/channel.pyx.pxi", line 353, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._segregated_call
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/channel.pyx.pxi", line 357, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._segregated_call
ValueError: Cannot invoke RPC on closed channel.

Ican't  establish causality in b/w the 2, seems one is misleading

Comment: This problem is being caused by a miss-usage of the `.stop()` function. You are closing some client that' being used. 1. Fix the credentials issue setting the correct variable. 2. Juts `del` when the job is finished and just if needed. It may not cause you any problem. Your original question seams to have no relations with the issues you are facing.

Comment: These errors are from before I used the .stop(). Yes you are right, I am deviating from my question. Will ask another one specific to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Thanks  a ton. Please post your final answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client objects are in memory objects if functions required for the interaction with google services, but they don't open network connection since they are created and keep it opened. So, having many objects created may not be a problem, since they are in memory allocations, like variables.

I have made a test creating thousands of clients in loop and there was no problem at all.

But, thay can be closed if you want. Basically just calling the following should delete them by:

```py
google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.cloud import storage

publisher_client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()     
client = storage.Client()

del publisher_client
del client
```

Its also recommended calling the following functions before del the objects:

`publisher_client.stop()`:

> Asynchronously sends all outstanding messages and prevents future calls to publish(). Method should be invoked prior to deleting this Client() object in order to ensure that no pending messages are lost.

`client.close()`:

Documentation is not very clear about it, but seams to close any files being read to be uploaded.

---

The another problem you have facing in production related to the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable is because you have to set it on the production env.

- Create a service account on GCP IAM console;
- Add proper permissions (Cloud Store Editor, Pub/Sub Editor (?))
- create a key on it (`json`) download and set env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to `/path/of/key/key.json`
- more details in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

For the Google Cloud Storage client, it seems like the `close()` method is only available in some language libraries.